# Completely center Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, view, centering, flutter-widget

I started to develop in Flutter recently and I am having difficulties in centralizing a Widget completely in the available space of View.

This is how it looks:

[image: How it looks]

And here's what I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

And here's my code:

```
        LayoutBuilder(builder:
            (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    NavHeader("Deposit"),
                    BalanceHeader(widget.usd),
                  ]),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "How much do you want deposit?",
                        style:( 
                          ...
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        width: width * 0.4,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          ...
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          ...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `MainAxisSize.min` The height of the Column will be according to the combined height of its children and incoming height from the parent will be ignored. That means your column height has shrinked to its children.

There is you can use `MainAxisSize.max` instead of `MainAxisSize.min` to max height of column. And also you have to use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` for aligning childrens to center of column.

**Your Second Column**

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Text(
      "How much do you want deposit?",
         style:( 
           ...
         ),
       ),
     Container(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       width: width * 0.4,
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
       child: Row(
         ...
       ),
     ),
   ],
 ),
```

**Edited Column**

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
  children: [
    Text(
      "How much do you want deposit?",
         style:( 
           ...
         ),
       ),
     Container(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       width: width * 0.4,
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
       child: Row(
         ...
       ),
     ),
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a widget for that!
As for most things in flutter just Wrap the Widgets you want centered inside a [`Center`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widget and you should achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi! I already tried wrapping my 2nd Column Widget with a Center Widget, but to make it work, I had to set manually the heightFactor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children ... Your code
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap your widget with the `Column` widget and it will work only for the X coordinates.

(It has already been stated but poorly)